# Can ViewBag and ViewData be used interchangeably?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was goofing around with MVC 5 and added the following code

```
@Code
    ViewData("AppName") = "Apricot"
End Code
```

Later in my Layout page I mistakenly used

```
Viewbag.AppName
```

and to my surprise it worked.  Is ViewBag simply wrapping ViewData

Answer (score 2):

Essentially yes. They are very similar and resolve to the same repository. ViewBag uses C# 4 dynamics and so its properties do not require casting the way Viewdata does. Otherwise you would use them the same. Neither is particularly recommended though.